# Ошибки и дебаггер, пользуясь ajax

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, javascript, django

**js:**

```
function _search() {
    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',

        url: 'frontend.views.get_content',

        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (json) {

            alert('success')
        },

        error: function () {
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}
$('.btn').click(_search);
```

**html:**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
```

В общем, пробуя сделать ajax запрос, я не получаю ничего - ни ошибки, ни успешного завершения, смотрю fire bug - вижу так же фигу.

Вопрос заключается в том, как **выследить ошибку**, а также какие способы контроля/дебагеры вы можете посоветовать?

Comment:      url: 'frontend.views.get_content'

Это как?

Comment: это из Django я пробовал несколько вариантов {% url 'get_content' %}, выявить ошибку это не должно помешать.

Comment: И всё-таки, какой урл.

Да, и укажите в начале Вашей функции следующее:

    function _search(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      
       ...
    }

,либо `return false;` [Почитать](http://olegorestov.ru/js/return_false_vs_preventdefault/)

Comment: @AlexeyAl, а вы в FireBug видите, как запрос отправляется, как возвращается ответ с сервера? И кстати, я тоже ваш URL не понимаю. Django или нет, но структура URL - одна для всех. Или у вас правила переадресации настроены как-то по-модному?

----------

>  либо return false

Для формы - без "либо"

Comment: C url все впорядке, т.к. есть похожий пример, где урл с таким синтаксисом работает, а в фаирбаге ничего не происходит, даже запроса нету...

Comment: @AlexeyAl, вы попробовали то, что рекомендовал @romeo? Думаю, что это должно помочь.

Comment: пробовал - 0 реакции

Comment: @AlexeyAl, в DOM-Ready код обёрнут?

    $(function(){
        $('.btn').click(_search);
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В FireBug во вкладке сеть можно найти текст ошибки.
Находите свой запрос, нажимаете на него и будет виден текст запроса и ответа.
Если там не одного запроса GET нет, значит что-то не стороне клиента